# Como pegar o percentual de espaço de armazenamento do banco de dados Postgre através do EF Core no Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-5, administração-postgresql

Preciso criar na minha aplicação uma funcionalidade que checa no banco de dados (`PostGreSQL`) o percentual de espaço utilizado do armazenamento para que seja mostrado em um gráfico.

Tenho um repositório genérico, e pensei em criar uma função `GetStorage()`, mas, não faço a mínima ideia de como isso deve ser feito, pois, não sei se o `EF Core` possui este recurso, será que isso deve ser feito usando `Script SQL`?

Alguma coisa parecida com o código abaixo, mas retornando o percentual:

```
public decimal GetStorage()
{
    var valor = Db.FromSql("SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('SistemaComercial'));";
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: Essa SQL traz o valor que você precisa?

Comment: Usando esse select no banco, ele me retorna o espaço ocupado em kilobytes. Eu precisava que fosse em percentual... Será que tem como fazer algum tipo de cálculo? Outro detalhe: A função é algo que eu montei, mas eu não sei como fazer com o EF Core, pois provavelmente, precisará executar sql.

Comment: Percentual sobre qual valor? existe sim a possibilidade de fazer um método para retornar o tamanho pg_database_size!

Comment: O percentual ocupado em relação ao tamanho total do banco de dados... Ele deve retornar o percentual ocupado com dados... Ex: Espaço ocupado 10%.

Comment: Na vdd, acho que será necessário fazer algum cálculo onde será descontado o tamanho total do Banco de Dados com o espaço usado..

Comment: O espaço utilizado ? tamanho do banco já tem !!! correto, mas, espaço do que ????

Comment: Espaço usado (Que já foi utilizado para gravação de dados).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74721/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-jalber-romano).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O espaço físico, em bytes, ocupado pela database `SistemaComercial` pode ser calculado por meio da função `pg_database_size()`:

```
SELECT pg_database_size( 'SistemaComercial' );
```

Para se obter o espaço livre de uma deteminada partição e/ou unidade, você pode escrever uma *stored procedure* usando a linguagem [`PL/Python`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpython.html), vejamos:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calcular_espaco_livre( path TEXT )
RETURNS BIGINT AS
$BODY$
    import os
    info = os.statvfs( path )
    return info.f_bsize * info.f_bavail
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Assim sendo, você pode escrever uma outra *stored procedure* em `PL/PgSQL` para resolver o seu problema:

```
CREATE FUNCTION obter_espaco_ocupado( dbnome TEXT )
RETURNS REAL AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    diretorio TEXT;
    livre BIGINT;
    ocupado BIGINT;
BEGIN
    -- Recupera o diretorio onde a database está instalada
    SELECT setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'data_directory' INTO diretorio;

    -- Calcula o espaco livre desse diretorio
    SELECT calcular_espaco_livre( diretorio ) INTO livre;

    -- Calcula o espaco ocupado pela database
    SELECT pg_database_size( dbnome ) INTO ocupado;

    -- Calcula a porcentagem ocupada
    RETURN (100.0 / livre) * ocupado;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Logo:

```
SELECT obter_espaco_ocupado( 'SistemaComercial' );
```

Comment: Obrigado @Lacobus!!!